# Keycloak with Angular and Spring error: GET http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/Storage/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to integrate Keycloak with Spring Boot and Angular.

Security works correctly. When I'm trying to access secured endpoint manually through browser `localhost:8080/products/1` *(products is entity in my database)*, then I'm redirected to Keycloak login client, after logging in I have access to the endpoint.

I've been folowing this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@pavankjadda/keycloak-with-angular-and-spring-boot-65ef06b83347).

Problem occurs when I'm trying to access `localhost:4200` *(Angular app main page)*, in browser console I receive this error:
[image: SCREENSHOT]

```
keycloak.js:1305 GET http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/Storage/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Spring configuration file:
***application-local.yml***

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: 'http://localhost:8180/auth'
  realm: 'Storage'
  resource: 'storage-app-client'
  public-client: true
  principal-attribute: test123
```

Rest of the configuration files is taken from tutorial mentioned above.

**Keycloak realm:**
[image: Security defenses]

**Keycloak initialization in Angular:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KeycloakService
{
  private keycloakAuth: KeycloakInstance;

  constructor()
  {
  }

  init(): Promise<any>
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      const config = {
        'url': 'http://localhost:8180/auth',
        'realm': 'Storage',
        'clientId': 'storage-app-client'
      };
      // @ts-ignore
      this.keycloakAuth = new Keycloak(config);
      this.keycloakAuth.init({onLoad: 'login-required'})
        .success(() =>
        {
          resolve();
        })
        .error(() =>
        {
          reject();
        });
    });
  }

  getToken(): string
  {
    return this.keycloakAuth.token;
  }

  logout()
  {
    const options = {
      'redirectUri': 'http://localhost:4200',
      'realm': 'Storage',
      'clientId': 'storage-app-client'
    };
    this.keycloakAuth.logout(options);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import {MainContentComponent} from './components/main-content/main-content.component';
import {ProductComponent} from './components/products/product/product.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import {ProductGroupComponent} from './components/productGroups/productGroup/product-group.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './components/footer/footer.component';
import {MatTableModule} from "@angular/material/table";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {ProductUpdateComponent} from './components/products/product-update/product-update.component';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {ProductCreateComponent} from './components/products/product-create/product-create.component';
import {MatSortModule} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {ProductGroupUpdateComponent} from './components/productGroups/product-group-update/product-group-update.component';
import {ProductGroupCreateComponent} from './components/productGroups/product-group-create/product-group-create.component';
import {MatExpansionModule} from "@angular/material/expansion";
import {MatSelectModule} from "@angular/material/select";
import {LogoutComponent} from "./components/logout/logout.component";
import {KeycloakService} from "./services/keycloak-service.service";
import {TokenInterceptor} from "./interceptors/token-interceptor";

export function kcFactory(keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
  return () => keycloakService.init();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MainContentComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductGroupComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProductUpdateComponent,
    ProductCreateComponent,
    ProductGroupUpdateComponent,
    ProductGroupCreateComponent,
    LogoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'products/update/:id', component: ProductUpdateComponent},
      {path: 'products/add', component: ProductCreateComponent},
      {path: 'groups', component: ProductGroupComponent},
      {path: 'groups/add', component: ProductGroupCreateComponent},
      {path: 'groups/update/:id', component: ProductGroupUpdateComponent},
      {path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent},
    ]),
    MatTableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [KeycloakService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: kcFactory,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Keycloak client**
[image]

Comment: Did u integrate with the keycloak-angular javascript adapter and initialized the keycloak config on the angular side?

Comment: post it in your question, also the app.module.ts

Comment: and also the screenshot of ur angular client config off keycloak

Comment: Getting the same problem (today). I have another app running alongside this client which works fine, but a separate angular app (different version of keycloak-angular mind you) is getting this exact same error.

Comment: I downgraded to keycloak-angular 7.3.1 in my newer angular app and the error has gone. I previously had 8.0.1.

I'm going to do more testing on 8.0.1 eventually but this unblocked me for now. Might be an incompatibility with my version of keycloak and the Angular library.

Comment: I have tried both versions and the outcome is the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111877/keycloak-with-angular-and-spring-error-get-http-localhost8180-auth-realms-st

Answer (score 16):

I feel your pain. I was following today this tutorial and got stuck in the same GET 404 error:

https://dev.to/anjnkmr/keycloak-integration-in-angular-application-5a43

The error comes from keycloak-js package. After a couple of hours of trying to find the cause I checked the release versions of keycloak-js and found that new version 11 was released 6 days ago (and which I was using).

I switched to version **10.0.2** for **keycloak-js** package.

To sum up here are the versions:

keycloak: 10.0.1

keycloak-js: 10.0.2

keycloak-angular: 8.0.1 (if you use it)

angular: 10** (in a desperate move I have upgraded from angular 9 to 10, I do not know if it had an impact)

Therefore for me it was the new version of keycloak-js package that caused all of the trouble.

I would suggest you try downgrading the version of keycloak-js to 10.0.2

Answer (score 4):

Try to use a version of keycloak.js from your keycloak server by path /auth/js/keycloak.js

> The library can be retrieved directly from the Keycloak server at /auth/js/keycloak.js and is also distributed as a ZIP archive.

> A best practice is to load the JavaScript adapter directly from Keycloak Server as it will automatically be updated when you upgrade the server. If you copy the adapter to your web application instead, make sure you upgrade the adapter only after you have upgraded the server.

You can refer [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_javascript_adapter) for futher details.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same. I used keycloak.js from server and my app is react.

in index html

```
<script src="https://sso-blabla.com/auth/js/keycloak.js"></script>
```

Then used this in react app like below

```
const Keycloak = window.Keycloak;
```

I am not sure this is the best way to do it. But I used like this because it was only a POC.

Answer (score 3):

My case was even more simpler, my local keycloak instance didn't respond to `/auth/*` URLs and always returned **page not found** error. It is because it works without proxy.
Once I removed `auth` from the url, it started to work.

Make sure your set up properly the keycloak URL when you init it.

For local environment I use:
`auth-server-url: 'http://localhost:8180/'`

For staging and production (because they run behind the proxy server with custom path `auth` added to it):
`auth-server-url: 'https://myServer/auth'`

BTW. I faced this problem with a new Keycloak version 18.0, previously it worked with `/auth/` in local too.

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite a bit of time researching this problem, here are some possible solutions that I found on other pages:

1. (this was my problem) - Incorrect real name - it's case sensitive and in my case I had entered "Master" instead of the correct one - "master"
2. Using a too recent keycloak-js version with an older keycloak server - solution is to downgrade to an older keycloak-js version
3. In some cases people had messed up their url - usually forgetting to add "/auth/ - e.g. the correct URL would be "https://example.com/auth/"
4. Wrong settings - ROOT URL or others could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On a rare occasion, perhaps the Keycloak URL is wrong as I did before. So, instead of `http://localhost:8282/auth` you specified `http://localhost:8282/keycloak/auth`

Answer (score 0):

I got that same exact error and the problem wasn't related with the front-end but with the backend version of keycloak. After I replaced the base image I was using for keycloak it fix the problem:

In this case I am using in package.json:

```
"keycloak-angular": "^8.4.0",
"keycloak-js": "^15.0.2",
```

and version 13.0.1 of keycloak.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: did you downgrade your keycloak version? if yes which version you used earlier

Answer (score 0):

1. Update package.json

`"keycloak-angular": "^8.4.0"`

`"keycloak-js": "^15.1.0"`

2. execute

`npm install`

3. execute

`ng serve`

Success!!!!

Answer (score 0):

change the "keycloak-js" lib to 10.0.2 version works to me.

my keycloak server version is:

Server Version  10.0.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue and I removed the "auth" from the keycloak.init at "app.init.ts" file and It's solved my issue:

config: {
url: 'http://localhost:8080',
// 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
realm: 'NybSys-Dev',
clientId: 'angular-web-client'
}

[image: keycloak issue solution]